# Should [aircraft] be a synonym of [aerobot]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I don't have enough rep in [aerobot](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aerobot) to propose this synonym officially, so I'm going to ask this question here.

Isn't [aircraft](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft), as it is currently used, a synonym of [aerobot](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aerobot)?

Here is the single question where [aircraft](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft) was used:

[How effective would the ARES aircraft be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/how-effective-ares-aircraft-would-be)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [aerobot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerobot) is, by definition, a robot. 
An [aeroplane/aircraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroplane) is a super-set to mean craft in air.

My preference would be to keep the two separate. Yet it might be better if the call were taken in the context of the question by the person posing the question.

Comment: I agree with your superset/subset analysis, but in the case of the question I pointed out the aircraft (superset) *is* an aerobot (subset) so the narrower tag is more applicable. Maybe making it a synonym is not the best solution because we *could* have questions about non-aerobot aircraft (such as aircraft used as an aerial launch platform).